# Efficiency operating in MySQL or PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a doubt.

I have a big query to get all the products of a web store, then I proccess the data to a CSV to synchronize to another external server, in this case DooFinder.

Now I am doing the proccess in the query. Example:

```
 - round((p.p_price*(SELECT tax_rate FROM tax_rates WHERE tax_rates.tax_rates_id=p.p_tax_class_id)/100)+p.p_price,2)
 - concat('https://www.domain.de/pimg/',p.p_image) AS image, p.manufacturers_id
```

**And the question is: What will be more efficient? Make the operations in the query or in PHP?** Now I have over 20 products in a test site and it works perfect, but the objective is have +1.000 products.

This is the query ($i is for each language, so +1.000 products * number of languages):

```
SELECT 
    pd.p_name,
    p.p_quantity, 
    concat('https://www.domain.de/pinf.php?products_id=',p.products_id) AS p_link,
    pd.p_description,
    p.p_id,
    p.p_tax_class_id, 
    p.p_date_available ,
    round((p.p_price*(SELECT tax_rate FROM tax_rates WHERE tax_rates.tax_rates_id=p.p_tax_class_id)/100)+p.p_price,2) AS price,
    concat('https://www.domain.de/pimg/',p.p_image) AS image, p.manufacturers_id
FROM 
    products p, 
    p_description pd, 
    p_to_categories ptc
WHERE 
        p.p_id = pd.p_id
    AND 
        pd.language_id = ".$i."
    AND 
        p.p_status=1
    AND 
        ptc.p_id = p.p_id
    AND 
        ptc.categories_id != 218
GROUP by p.p_id
```

Comment: There's no way to know definitively without testing both approaches, but chances are that, unless your DB is badly indexed or denormalised or whatever, then doing operations on large amounts of data like this is likely to be faster in SQL, which can do it as a set operation on all the rows, rather than by looping over each one and executing the same logic separately and repeatedly, which PHP would have to do.

Comment: Nobody here can possibly answer that question accurately for you, and it would be very easy for you to benchmark it both ways.

Comment: As others have said, just benchmarking will give you the right answer, but my guess is that you won't be fetching 1000 rows at once, in that case, with a limit on this query perhaps mysql will be the fastest option, but that depends on your use case. I don't recall where I read that, but many database functions are faster than parsing, evaluating and formatting in PHP.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. So I will test it with benchmarking tools. I just googled and there are some tools to make this job. 

I know that it will be a question without a real answer. Should I close it or let it opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deciding whether to perform the computations on the client or on the database server, you should consider the following:

- Which one has more spare CPU cycles?
- Will making the client do the computation require additional data transfer from the server? If doing it on the server reduces the data transfer, it may be worthwhile to make the database CPU work a bit harder.
- Can you reduce the data transfer by making the client compute the result? E.g. suppose the client displays 100 computations based on one column. In that case it makes sense to fetch just that column instead of all of the computations based on it.

In your specific example, the overhead of extra computations is going to be marginal relative to the rest of the query, so if you already have it coded to do it on the server, I would leave it like that. At the same time, if you are doing it on the client, it is not that bad either, so I would still not bother refactoring.

However, there is one thing that I would fix - rewrite the tax rate sub-select as a join. This one would have more overhead than any of the computations even if properly optimized by the MySQL optimizer.

And, of course, as was suggested in the comments, benchmark your performance and make decisions based on those measurements. Proper benchmarking aside from the obvious has a side benefit of helping find odd performance and even functionality bugs that otherwise would have been found by your users at the worst possible time.